# Erro na criação do banco com o Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js, sequelize-js

Opa,
Estou criando uma API Rest em Nodejs e usando o Sequelize como ORM só que quando tento usar o comando db:create do sequelize pra criar a database, ele me retorna esse erro:

**ERROR: Dialect [object Object] does not support db:create / db:drop commands**

Queria saber como resolvo esse problema, ai vai o código:

```
module.exports = {
    dbconfig: {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost:3306s',
        username: 'root',
        password: 'toor150',
        database: 'lynho_barber',
        define: {
            timestamps: true,
            underscored: true
        }
    },

};
```

O código acima é o objeto que guarda as informações de parametro do sequelize

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const variables = require('../config/variables');

const connection = new Sequelize(variables.dbconfig);

module.exports = connection;
```

Esse acima é o codigo de conexão do sequelize.

Comment: A resposta resolveu seu problema? Existe alguma dúvida pendente? Se a dúvida estiver solucionada, considere aceitar a resposta. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não está inicializando o Sequelize da maneira correta. A inicialização do Sequelize deve ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', { options });
```

No seu caso:

```js
const connection = new Sequelize(
    variables.dbconfig.database,
    variables.dbconfig.username,
    variables.dbconfig.password,
    variables.dbconfig
);
```

Veja mais exemplos na [documentação](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html).

Comment: tentei desta forma e tambem nao deu certo. Ja tentei ate inicializar em formato de URI e o erro persiste

Comment: O `localhost:3306` possui um `s` no final. No seu código está assim também ou foi erro de digitação na pergunta?

Comment: tava assim também no código mas eu ja corrigi e o erro continua

Comment: E o erro continua o mesmo? Você possui o pacote `mysql2` instalado?

Answer (score -2):

cara o dialeto que voce esta usando no caso mysql, nao suporta o  db:create.  faz o seguinte , atualiza seu npm , e reinstala o sequelize, reinicia seu SGBD e caso tenha instalado o mysql2 reinstala ele também, se nao tiver instalado , instala ai.